# Monitor application running on docker at EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, alert

I have nodejs application in docker on AWS EC2 instance. It exposes port. Sometimes this application terminates and I am not able to restart it automatically. What would be the best approach on AWS EC2 in order to check and restart in case of failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to use [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/)

Very easy to install and configure. It will start the application when the system starts up and also monitors it. If the application is not running, it will start the application.

[Adding a Program](http://supervisord.org/running.html#adding-a-program)